# Create post revision on slug change

Tags: actions, save-post

I'd like to be able to track changes in the slug / `post_name` field of the post.

I've tried using `wp_save_post_revision(...);` if I detect a slug change, but according to [this page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Revisions) wordpress only tracks specific fields, `post_name` not being one of them.

Am I SOL or is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

If you're comfortable with PHP, it would be possible to keep track of when the slug is updated. The only way I can think of is a bit complicated:

1. Make sure revisions are enabled, both for your install and for the post type you're targeting. You'll have to determine how many revisions you want to save, which will be a balance between how many times you think someone might change the post (whether it's a slug change, or content, or anything about the post) and how bloated you allow the database to become with all that extra data.
2. Add version control for a postmeta field you will use to keep track of the slug with every revision. First install the plugin "[WP-Post-Meta-Revisions](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-post-meta-revisions/)." Then, in a custom plugin, or a child theme's `functions.php` file:

```php
add_filter('wp_post_revision_meta_keys', 'wpse_track_slug_postmeta');

function wpse_track_slug_postmeta() {
    // Access the array of postmeta keys that is already versioned
    global $versionedKeys;

    // Add your custom postmeta key to the array
    $versionedKeys[] = 'versionedSlug';

    // Pass the array back to WordPress
    return $versionedKeys;
}
```

Once this is done, every time you save a revision, the postmeta "versionedSlug" for that specific revision will be saved.

3. Every time a revision is saved, you need to tell WP to save the slug as that "versionedSlug" postmeta. You can use the `wp_insert_post` hook:

```php
// Every time WP inserts a post, run this function
add_action('wp_insert_post', 'wpse_save_slug_postmeta');

function wpse_save_slug_postmeta($post_id, $post, $update) {
    // Make sure this is a revision
    if(wp_is_post_revision($post_id)) {
        // Save the slug as postmeta
        // First parameter is the post ID of the revision
        // Second parameter is what you want to call this postmeta key
        // Third parameter is what you're saving - the slug itself
        update_post_meta($post->ID, 'versionedSlug', $post->slug);
    }
}
```

You will then have to decide how you want to access this data. If you just want to browse a post's revisions, the revision comparison view will show you when the slug changed because it's now explicitly saved as postmeta. You could also create various reports or widgets, depending on your needs.